# How to "mock" Sentry client in the PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, sentry

In case if you need to test PHP application error handlers, you have to "mock" or just disable sending errors on remote servers in the Sentry client. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example for Laravel, but this approach should work for any framework.

```
use Sentry\Client;
use Sentry\EventFactory;
use Sentry\Options;
use Sentry\Serializer\RepresentationSerializer;
use Sentry\Serializer\Serializer;
use Sentry\Transport\NullTransport;

private function mockSentry(): void
{
    /** @var \Sentry\State\Hub $sentry */
    $sentry = $this->app['sentry']; // Get sentry object from Laravel's container

    $client = new Client(
        new Options(),
        new NullTransport(),
        new EventFactory(
            new Serializer(new Options()),
            new RepresentationSerializer(new Options()),
            new Options(),
            '1',
            '1',
        ),
    );
    $sentry->bindClient($client);
}
```

Comment: why are you answering your own question not even one minute later?

Comment: @ArSeN because it's encouraged https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I'm using Laravel 6.11 and sentry-laravel:1.71., the config has been set up according to rhe docs problem now is resolving sentry out from the service container in my handler test, I keep getting `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [sentry] does not exist.` any ideas why I am not able to resolve sentry from the container? I also could not resolve anything atall from the container